# If not async function is awaited and throws, should caller code throw too?

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
function boo() { throw new Error(); }
let foo = await boo();
```

I expect it will throw as if there was not the `await` expression. (Note, `boo` is not an async function.) However, I fail to find description of this code behavior in the ECMAScript spec.

Here is how await expression [should be executed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
AwaitExpression : await UnaryExpression
1. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
2. Let value be ? GetValue(exprRef).
3. Return ? Await(value).
```

`GetValue` results with an abrupt completion, so [`Await`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await) routine gets it as an argument.

It is the place where things become unclear to me. The `Await` wraps `value` in a promise. It is achieved with an aid of [`PromiseResolve`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve) procedure, which *resolves* the promise with `value`.

So should `foo` be set to an instance of `Error` thrown from `boo`? It is of course nonsense. But I am tied in knots and can't find another way in the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `GetValue` results with an abrupt completion, so `Await` routine gets it as an argument.

No, the `Await` abstract operation is never executed. You're missing the (subtle) `?` sign in front of `?GetValue(exprRef)`, which is [a shorthand for `ReturnIfAbrupt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-returnifabrupt-shorthands):

```
2. Let value be ReturnIfAbrupt(GetValue(exprRef))
```

so if there's an abrupt completion, it will just terminate the evaluation of the `await` and return the abrupt completion to the evaluation of the assignment expression.